# How to change date type from 'year_week' to 'day_month_year' format in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

[Image of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woASB.png)

I have a dataset but date is given in year_week format. I want to change it to normal 'day_month_year' format and set it as an index.

```py
df["Date"] = df["year_week"].astype(str)
df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strptime("{}-{}-1".format(int(df['Date'].split('-')[0]),  int(df['Date'].split('-')[1])), '%Y-%W-%w')
df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
df.drop('year_week',inplace=True,axis=1)
df.head()
```

but it gives bad month numver 13; must be 1-12 error`your text`

Answer (score 1):

append the weekday as a string (see also: [strftime/strptime formatting codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)), parse to datetime, then format to string in desired format:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"year_week": ["2020-01", "2020-02"]})

# parse to datetime, then format to string
df["day_month_year"] = pd.to_datetime(df["year_week"]+"-0", format="%Y-%W-%w").dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

print(df)
  year_week day_month_year
0   2020-01     12-01-2020
1   2020-02     19-01-2020
```